# same logic, different data with no result

Tags: javascript, onchange

There is some minute mistake i may be doing here. Here are two fiddles that has the same logic with different data. One works (http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/2176/), one doesnt (http://jsfiddle.net/4h4qhynj/)

I am sure I may have done some mistake and trying to find since an hour but not getting it. please help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // On changing the select option, display the rows which are relevant to the option selected.

    $(document).on('change', '.Cat_Table_Header', function () {
alert("ok");
        $('#catleads tbody tr').each(function (trIndex, tr) {
            var visible = true;
            $('.Cat_Table_Header').each(function (selectIndex, select) {
                $option = $(select).find('option:selected');
                $td = $(tr).find('td').eq(selectIndex);
                visible = visible && ($option.val() == 'all' || $td.text() == $option.text());
            });
            if (visible) {
                $(tr).show();
            } else {
                $(tr).hide();
            }
        });

    });


});
```

Comment: Your second fiddle doesn't have jQuery loaded.

Comment: It works when I add jQuery in the Frameworks menu: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4h4qhynj/1/

Comment: oh! jQuery reference is required for this?? so can i add this to my file? <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: If you had just opened a console you would have immediately seen the error `$ is not defined`. Please get used to using debugging tools -- it will save you a world of headaches.

Comment: Of course it is. What do you think all the `$(...)` stuff is?

Comment: You knew enough to select jQuery in the first fiddle, how could you not know about it in the second one?

Comment: Don't be so harsh dude. :D

Comment: Thanks.. i dont know javascript. i was researching and studying and i found this fiddle so i thought of replicating this with a sample example. thankx. so now i believe adding this will solve the problem right?  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: first fiddle was not mine... i searched for it

Comment: `jquery/jquery-latest.js` is a local path. If that's where that file exists, then yes, you could add that (to your **local** development project). If you're still just *fiddling* around (ha!), then simply pick an appropriate version of jQuery from the Frameworks & Extensions area (top left).

Comment: Thank you so much all of you. have a nice time!